# How to make a unicode variable in C?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, printf

I want to write a program where if a user inputs 3s the program can print into the console the character "", for input kh output "", for input 10c output "" etc. I have a list of unicodes from [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode).

[Unicode for Card symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCh39.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct card {
    int val;
    char suite;
} card;

void Take(card myCard[]);
void Display(card Cards[], int num);

void main()
{
    card myCards[13];
    int remaining = 13;
    printf("Enter you cards:");
    Take(myCards);
    printf("Your cards are:");
    Display(myCards, remaining);
    while(remaining > 0)
    {
        remaining--;
    }
}    

void Take(card myCard[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        scanf("%d%c", &myCard[i].val, &myCard[i].suite); 
}

void Display(card cards[], int num)
{    
    char unicode[7];
    int i = 0; 
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        strcpy(unicode, "\u1F0");
        switch(cards[i].suite)
        {
            case 's':
                strcat(unicode, "A");
                break;    
            case 'h':
                strcat(unicode, "B");
                break;    
            case 'b':
                strcat(unicode, "C");
                break;    
            case 'c':
                strcat(unicode, "D");
                break;    
        }
        switch(cards[i].val)
        {
            case 10:
                strcpy(unicode, "A");
                break;
            case 11:
                strcpy(unicode, "B");
                break;
            case 12:
                strcpy(unicode, "D");
                break;
            case 13:
                strcpy(unicode, "E");
                break;    
            default:
                break;
        }
        printf("%s\t", unicode);
    }
}
```

There is a pattern in the unicode as \u1f0XY where x from A through D changes the suite and Y from 1 through E changes the value of the card. My approach was to create a string called Unicode which has the initial value of "\u1f0". Then depending upon what suite the card is, I will append the string with proper x and then depending upon the value I will append the Unicode string with the proper y. 
    That is, my approach was to create a variable string which would contain the correct Unicode for the sting to be printed. But I am getting this error

> error: incomplete universal character name \u1F0
>                strcpy(unicode, "\u1F0");

How can I create a variable Unicode correctly or is it impossible the way I'm thinking it to do?

Comment: Unicode character syntax os a small problem, you may have more hoops to jump through. What platform are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a not so common use case with unicode characters outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) that is with a unicode code greater than U+FFFF. Those characters can be represented in C litteral with an uppercase U prefix followed with 8 hexa chars, and are converted in their UTF8 representation. Typically the ace of spades is `"\U0001FA01"` or `"\xf0\x9f\x82\xa1"`. All your cards will have the 2 same common first bytes and only last two will vary. Once you know it, and know how the UTF-8 encoding works, you can write your `Display` function that way:

```
void Display(card cards[], int num)
{    
    char unicode[7] = "\U0001FA00";
    int i = 0; 
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        switch(cards[i].suite)
        {
            case 's':
                unicode[2] = 0x82;
                unicode[3] = 0xA0;
                 break;    
            case 'h':
                unicode[2] = 0x82;
                unicode[3] = 0xB0;
                break;    
            case 'b':
                unicode[2] = 0x83;
                unicode[3] = 0x80;
                break;    
            case 'c':
                unicode[2] = 0x83;
                unicode[3] = 0x90;
                break;    
        }
        unicode[3] += cards[i].val;
        if(cards[i].val >= 12)
        {
            unicode[3] += 1;
        }
        printf("%s\t", unicode);
    }
}
```

I could not really test the display, because my terminal can only display unicode characters from the BMP.

Answer (score 1):

Constant string literals are a compile-time thing, and their escape sequences are handled by the compiler, and can not be set at run-time.

In your case it might be easier to set up the full Unicode character in the cases, instead of attempting to constructing it piecewise.

As in

```
switch(cards[i].suite)
{
    case 's':
        strcpy(unicode, "\u1F0A");
        break;    
    case 'h':
        strcpy(unicode, "\u1F0B");
        break;    
    case 'b':
        strcpy(unicode, "\u1F0C");
        break;    
    case 'c':
        strcpy(unicode, "\u1F0D");
        break;    
}
```